# Python: Get number from a non-sepreted string. Using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am working on convert a chemical formular to the proportion of elements by using python.

for example:
I have a list of `["Ti5Cu3", "TiCu2", "Ti2Cu3"]` as input list, and want to convert it to `[5/(5+3), 1/(1+2), 2/(2+3)]`.

How can I get the number behind the element mark? I think that `re` library might be useful? And how to use it to solve my problem?

My solution now is:

```
def formula2por(s):                             
    if s == "Ti":       
        return 1
    elseif s == "Cu":
        return 0
    else:                                       
        t = re.match(r'Ti(.*)Cu(.*)', s).groups()
        # pdb.set_trace()                       
        if t[0] is not '':
            x = int(t[0])
        else:
            x = 1       
        if t[1] is not '':
            y = int(t[1])                                                                        
        else:                                   
            y = 1                               
        return round(x/(x+y), 4)
```

However, I think it is mussy and not a pythonic way for this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, but what are you actually converting those molecules to?  The molecular weights of titanium and copper are not 5, 3, 2, etc.  I ask this because I don't understand your conversion, and therefore cannot suggest a regex for your problem.

Comment: I guess your first task will be to split the string before each capital letter.

Comment: What is the format of your strings? Do you only have 2-element molecules? Could you have C2H10O6? Do you want the result to be numbers or strings? For example the string "1/(1+2)" represents a calculation that equals 1/2 (do you want the number or the string?)

Comment: I am sorry that I did not describe my demand clearly. I want get the output of flot type which represent the proportion of the titanium @Tim. And the input sets are "TixCuy" strings, but also contain "Ti" and "Cu".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *`Ti(\d*)Cu(\d*)`* to capture the digits and pass the matched object to a *replacement* function; where the digits can be accessed as the first and second captured group respectively:

```
lst = ["Ti5Cu3", "TiCu2", "Ti2Cu3"]
​
def div_sub(match):
    x, y = match.group(1), match.group(2)
    x = 1 if x == '' else int(x)
    y = 1 if y == '' else int(y)
    return str(x/(x+y))
​
import re
[float(re.sub(r"Ti(\d*)Cu(\d*)", div_sub, s)) for s in lst]
# [0.625, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4]
```

Comment: That is better that mine.  But, what if the input alse contains "Ti" and "Cu"? By adding more if else clause? Or there is better way in modified the regex pattern? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some example inputs that doesn't fit `Ti[0-9]Cu[0-9]`? You might still be able to use regex pattern depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle this if we make the assumption that you have none of the three letter codes. Then,

```
def calculate(match):
    i = 1, tmp = []
    while match.group(i) != '':
         if match.group(i+1) == '':
             tmp.append(1.0)
         else:
             tmp.append(float(match.group(i+1)))
         i += 2
    if i == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return tmp[0]/sum(tmp)


import re
required_list = []
pattern = re.compile("^([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d*\.?\d*)([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d*\.?\d*)")
for compound in lst:
    required_list.append(calculate(pattern.match(compound)))
```

As you can see, this code can easily be adapted to multi element compounds like potassium permanganate and handles floating point indices.